# CakePHP: Filter Index() with session's user ID

Tags: php, cakephp, filter

I have a small cakePHP app that allows for user's to login and be provided a session to give their status on an assigned project.

I am replacing the baked view portion of the add() function that asks which user to create a new status report for under with this line of code in the controller:

```
$this->data['Status']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
```

I would like to do something similar in the index() function so that users could also, only see the their previous status reports and not any other users.

How would I attempt to filter the index() function?

```
function index() {
    $this->Status->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('statuses', $this->paginate());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set your conditions in the paginate variable:

```
function index() {
    $this->paginate = array(
        'recursive' => 0,
        'conditions' => array('Status.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
    );
    $this->set('statuses', $this->paginate('Status'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at setting [custom pagination queries](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1237/Custom-Query-Pagination). The cakePHP book (linked) is a great resource for this.