# CakePHP: Filter content based on logged in user

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, filter

I'm building a small CakePHP app with user authentication.

What is the best practice for filtering content by user so that users only see their own stuff?

I've seen this post but it hardly seems like an efficient option as it implies a condition is to be added to every action

> [CakePHP: Filter Index() with session's user ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652951/cakephp-filter-index-with-sessions-user-id)

Is it recommended to add a `beforeFilter` in the AppModel which would filter by the authenticated user's ID or does Cake have a built-in way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no in-built way of doing this, and there's any number of solutions that could work.

The best way all depends on your situation. In some cases, doing it on a per-action basis, like the question you linked to, would be best. In other cases a more generic solution, such as writing a `beforeFind` method for your Model/s, or even for your AppModel, would be better.

Which solution is best depends on your exact requirements. Eg, if users can absolutely, always, only ever view their own content, and if every table is linked to a user via a user_id field, then a more generic solution will work.

However, if it's more varied and there are only some actions, of some controllers, that need to be restricted based on the current logged in user, then a less generic approach (such as the one you linked to) is needed.

Comment: Thank you. Could you give an example of a beforeFind() filter on a Model? (ex: Cloud storage solution where users can only access their own files)

Comment: I can't really give you an example without knowing the ins and outs of your app, sorry. The doco is here, though: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforefind